# how to pass values to object variables

Tags: vb.net

I have a Class Called Student in vb.net 2012. with a method called read, which, when called, retrieves a student with ID, Name, Admission, and other details.

and another inherited form that is used to display details of students and other objects in the application (program, classlevels, departments, etc.)

```
    Public Sub Createnewrecord() Implements IMyObjects.CreateNewRecord
    Dim frm As Object = GetObjectTypes(ManagedObjectChild)
    frm.state = PublicTypes.FORM_STATE.AddStateMode
    frm.loadform()
    End Sub
```

in the New button I call Createnewrecord and i am able to open form NewObject based on managedobject and managed objectchild that i set in inherited form's properties.

to delete an Item I try this

```
public Sub DeleteSelectedRecord(byval SelectedItemCode as string)
dim ObjectOfManagedObjectType as object=GetObjectTypes(ManagedObject) 
' return a new   Managed object as for GetObjectTypes below 
ObjectOfManagedObjectType=ObjectOfManagedObjectType.read(selectedItemCode)
objectOfManagedObjectType.delete

' Say the managed object is  Student class, ObjectofManagedobjecttype =new 
Student(selecteditemcode) would return a new student object with accessible code, name
and every detail. the class is implemented and working fine. As for the implementation of the class, the delete method deletes an item like where itemcode=me.code.
```

when i test the ObjectofmanagedOBjectType, it is nothing and therefore the properties contain no values.

i dont undestand why as in the debuger, I see the read method is actually executed and retuns a object that is valid( with values in the property). I attach I attach the dependent functions. Is there a work around, or a better way to do this? I heared about reflection but I don't know how to used it.

```
    Public Function GetObjectTypes(ByVal objectT As PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE) As Object

    Select Case objectT
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.ClassLevel
            Return New ClassLevel
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Department
            Return New Department
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Fee
            Return New Fee
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Level
            Return New Level
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.SchoolYear
            Return New SchoolYear
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.SchoolYearAE
            Return New frmSchoolYearAE
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Program
            Return New Program
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.programAE
            Return New frmProgramAE
        Case PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE.Student
            Return New Student
    End Select
    Return Nothing
End Function

Public Enum OBJECT_TYPE
    Program
    programAE
    Student
    StudentAE
    Level
    LevelAE
    SchoolYear
    SchoolYearAE
    Department
    DepartmentAE
    ClassLevel
    ClassLevelAE
    Fee
End Enum
```

Comment: You should read over your post again and add all code and add a better and more detailed explanation of your problem. I've read it 3 times now and I still can't figure out what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am such an Idiot! Sory.     Public Sub DeleteObject(ByVal ObjectTypeName As PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE, ByVal ObjectCode As String)
        Dim MYobject As Object = GetObjectTypes(ObjectTypeName)
        Dim objectToDelete As Object = MYobject.read(ObjectCode)
        objectToDelete.delete()
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted to achieve.

```
    Public Sub DeleteObject(ByVal ObjectTypeName As PublicTypes.OBJECT_TYPE, ByVal   ObjectCode As String)
    Dim MYobject As Object = GetObjectTypes(ObjectTypeName)
    Dim objectToDelete As Object = MYobject.read(ObjectCode)
    objectToDelete.Delete()
End Sub
```